# Can a character wield a two-handed or large weapon in one hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

Some class and race features allow a character to "count as one size larger
when determining your carrying capacity and the weight you can push, drag, or lift." (Eberron warforged Juggernaut) or "Your carrying capacity (including maximum load and maximum lift)
is doubled, and you have advantage on Strength checks made to push, pull, lift, or break objects." (barbarian path of the totem bear)

Would these characters be able to wield a two-handed weapon (eg maul) with one hand?
Alternatively, can a larger version of a one-handed weapon be used to give more damage? This seems to work for the "enlarge" spell, so could it work through non-magical means?

Comment: The title and the body seem to be asking two different things; the title asks if an _actual_ large creature can wield a two handed weapon (without specifying in one hand or not), whereas the body asks whether a _medium_ creature with a certain feature can wield a two-handed weapon in one hand. I'm guessing the body is what you're really asking and the title is wrong?

Comment: Related questions (do any of these answer your question?): "[Is there any way for a Medium PC to wield a 2-handed sword in one hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88733)" and "[Can I dual wield two-handed weapons in D&D 5E?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65725)" and "[Can larger than medium creatures use two-handed weapons with one hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108891)"

Comment: @Medix2 It seems to be a duplicate of the last link you posted.

Comment: edited to clarify and reduce duplication, focusing on large one-handed weapons

Comment: If you feel the various links have not answered your question, please edit to explain why or what isn't covered in those